# Divide polynomial into equally lengths in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, polynomial-math, polynomials

I have the equation of a third order polynomial and two points lying on that polygon.I also can calculate the length of the polygon between these points with the opencv arcLength function.

How do I get these equally distributed points, which divide the polygon into N parts with the same length?

[image: Problem visualization]

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this can help. In what follows:

```
 f = polynomial
 f' = derivative of f
 N = Number of subdivisions
 D = length of each subdivisions
 a = x coordinate of f for the first end of the curve.
 M = max of f' in the interval [a, b] where the curve is to be drawn.
 k = an integer such that an error of M/k would be negligible
```

**Algorithm**

- For every `1 <= j <= N - 1`, find `n(j)` such that the following `sum(j)` approaches `jD` by less than `M/k`:

  ```
  sum(j) = sum from i=1 to n(j) of sqrt(1 + f'(a + (i-1)/k)^2)/k
  ```

**Idea of the algorithm**

The quantity:

```
1/k * sqrt(1 + f'(a + (i-1)/k)^2)
```

is the approximate length of the curve between `a + (i-1)/k` and `a + i/k`.

The idea of the algorithm is to sum the lengths of these small curve segments trying to find which ones are close enough to `D`, `2D`, `3D`, etc.